# App crash while using react Navigation@4.02

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {  createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Splash from './Components/Splash';
import MainScreen from './Components/MainScreen';

const BasedNavigator=createStackNavigator({
    Splash:Splash,
    MainScreen:MainScreen,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Splash',
}
)

const Container=createAppContainer(BasedNavigator);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Container />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
};

export default App;
```

when i add react navigation@4.02 it start crashing..i m using before react-navigation@4.02 it work correctly for me before,after @4.02  now i don't understand why it does not work

Comment: please let me know your RN version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error after using the modules

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
```

Please try

```
$ react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
$ react-native link react-native-reanimated
$ react-native link react-native-screens
```

the solution is working for me.

and the other reason can be

[image]

[React-navigation Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-into-an-expo-managed-project)

Answer (score 1):

There is some migration in version 4.

For example, createStackNavigator migrated to the react-navigation-stack library.

You have to read the document again :)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html